# Remove the gap on the left side of some text in a div

Tags: html, css

**What I have:** I'm trying to remove the gap between padding and text so that the information and title perfectly align on the left side. The image below shows that the text `10` has some kind of gap on the left side (marked by myself using a red rectangle).

[image]

Here is the HTML part.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="widgetText">10</div>
        <div class="widgetSubtitle">subtitle</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS for `widgetText` and `widgetSubtitle`.

```
.widgetText {
    font-size: 44px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 4px;
    border-left-color: black;
}

.widgetSubtitle {
    font-size: 12px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 4px;
    border-left-color: black;
    color: gray
}
```

**Actual question:** How can I remove the gap as marked with the red rectangle in the picture above?

**What I tried so far:** I played around with padding and all the sorts. But looking into the box info of Chromes development mode clearly shows that there is a gap that is not related to the padding. I couldn't find any other solution to this apart from a negative left padding.

[image]

Comment: you could add a negative padding to it, let's say `padding-left: -5px` should do the job. But that might not be the issue, try with 00 on the text to see if that padding/margin is really there. It might just be the font. Anyway, if it is the font but you still want that padding you can set it conditionally if the first digit is 1 for instance.

Comment: You almost certainly **can't**. I would suggest that the 'space' is part of the font/character glyph. It's there for a reason...to stop characters running into one another,

Comment: have you tried negative margins ?

Comment: in widgetText you are displaying number or text. @Stephan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, there is no spacing. The little space comes from the huge font size you have applied for widgetText.

Nagative padding is invalid CSS.

What you could do is wrap the text in another div and set a negative margin to it. But the margin depends on your font size if you really want to stick the text next to the left border without any spacing.

Answer (score 2):

Many ways.
use negative margin instead
in html:
   `<div class="widgetText"><span>10</span></div>`

and in css:

```
 .widgetText span {
margin-left: -5px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The space is due to font. If the space is your concern, add `text-indent: -4px;` into widget text

```css
.widgetText {
    font-size: 44px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 4px;
    border-left-color: black;
    text-indent: -0.25em;
    
}

.widgetSubtitle {
    font-size: 12px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 4px;
    border-left-color: black;
    color: gray
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="widgetText">10</div>
        <div class="widgetSubtitle">subtitle</div>
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd suggest an `em` value rather than `px`...you want the gap related to the font-size.

Comment: Can u just give detail why should i use em instead of px

Comment: I just did....if the font-size is 72 px, your 4px adjustment probably won't be enough...if you size it in `em` the gaps will always relate to the font-size...I'd suggest `0.25em`

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken for there is no extra padding rather it's before "10".It's the actual space that is required to for printing "10" and no any other extra spaces are acquired.[image]

[image]

[image]

look at the images for the spaces acquired.

And no -ve padding will affect the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wanted to do this. After reading the suggestions above I thought I'd try to compute the gap by drawing the text to a canvas, checking where it starts in the canvas by finding the first non-empty column of pixels, and then  setting the margin to move the div that amount. It might work for some case

```js
const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');

const cache = new Map();

function isColumnEmpty(pixels, width, height, x) {
  for (let y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    const offset = y * width + x;
    if (pixels[offset]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function getGap(element) {
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
  const left =
      style.textAlign === 'left' || 
      (style.textAlign === 'start' && style.direction === 'ltr') ||
      (style.textAlign === 'end' && style.direction === 'rtl');
  const right =
      style.textAlign === 'right' ||
      (style.textAlign === 'start' && style.direction === 'rtl') ||
      (style.textAlign === 'end' && style.direction === 'ltr');
  const font = `${style.fontWeight} ${style.fontSize} ${style.fontFamily}`;
  const text = element.textContent;
  const width = 128;
  const height = element.clientHeight;
  const char = right
      ? text.substring(text.length - 1, text.length)
      : text.substring(0, 1);
  const key = `${font} ${window.devicePixelRatio} ${height} ${style.textAlign} + ${char}`;
  let gap = cache.get(key);
  if (gap === undefined) {
    gap = 0;
    if (height && (left || right)) {
      const dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
      ctx.canvas.width = width * dpr;
      ctx.canvas.height = height * dpr;
      ctx.scale(dpr, dpr);
      ctx.font = font;
      ctx.textAlign = right ? 'right' : 'left';

      ctx.fillText(text, right ? width - 1 : 0, height);

      const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
      const pixels = new Uint32Array(imgData.data.buffer);

      const delta = right ? -1 : 1;
      const start = right ? imgData.width - 1 : 0;
      const end = right ? -1 : imgData.width;

      let x = start;
      for (; x !== end; x += delta) {
        if (!isColumnEmpty(pixels, imgData.width, imgData.height, x)) {
          break;
        }
      }

      gap = (start - x) * delta / dpr;
    }
    cache.set(key, gap);
  }

  const margin = `${gap}px`;
  return {
    gap,
    styles: [
      ['marginLeft', left ? margin : '0'],
      ['marginRight', right ? margin : '0'],
    ],
  };
}

function removeGap(element) {
  const {styles} = getGap(element);
  for (const [prop, value] of styles) {
    element.style[prop] = value;
  }
}


document.querySelectorAll('.align').forEach(elem => {
  removeGap(elem);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: orange;
}
.foo {
  font-size: 80pt;
}
.bar {
  font-size: 80pt;
  text-align: right;
}
pre {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<pre>not aligned</pre>
<div class="foo">123</div>
<pre>aligned</pre>
<div class="align foo">123</div>
<pre>not aligned</pre>
<div class="bar">456</div>
<pre>aligned</pre>
<div class="align bar">456</div>
```